# Laravel after update (5.3 => 5.4) produces wrong sql

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, orm, laravel-5.4

I have stable project with Laravel 5.3.

Today decided to upgrade Laravel to 5.4 and then to 5.5. I am following to official upgrade guide.

After 5.4 upgrade everything seems to work.. except one thing. One of my multiple `belongsToMany` relationships produces now wrong sql.

I have model `App\Situation` with relationship:

```
public function feedbacks()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Feedback');
  }
```

And `App\Feedback` model with:

```
public function situations()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Situation');
  }
```

Of course I have tables `feedbacks`, `situations` and `feedback_situation`.
Before upgrade this code was fine:

```
dd($situation->feedbacks);
```

But now it produces exception:

> Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'example.feedback'
>   doesn't exist (SQL: select `feedback`.*,
>   `feedback_situation`.`situation_id` as `pivot_situation_id`,
>   `feedback_situation`.`feedback_id` as `pivot_feedback_id` from
>   `feedback` inner join `feedback_situation` on `feedback`.`id` =
>   `feedback_situation`.`feedback_id` where
>   `feedback_situation`.`situation_id` = 383)

It's very weird because other relationships works, and this one worked on 5.3.

Comment: its searching for a table feedback not feedback**s**

Comment: That's why I'm asking. It should search feedbacks table. It was searching feedbacks table at L5.3!

Comment: add protected `$table = 'feedbacks';` into your feedback model

Comment: It worked. Thank you. Post your answer please. If you know why it became broken, I would glad to read it :)

Comment: don't know why is broken, yet :(

Comment: It's interesting, it's about plural form of word. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/176805/plural-of-feedback says that `many feedbacks` is wrong, we must say `many feedback` (like many data, not datas). It was probably a bug in 5.3, not 5.4.

Comment: yes, you are right see: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Support/Pluralizer.php, the word is added to the uncountable array

Comment: its in 5.3 ass well, it was added after  Oct 13, 2016 https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/430abe34496e8f6ee1678493e10c80305c968025#diff-23d81392342e9ec4ab4507e4f7978cd3

Comment: It's strange then, I'm absolutly sure I was using 5.3 for a year minimum and there were no errors with `feedbacks`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add protected `$table = 'feedbacks';` into your feedback model to change the name that the model uses to `feedbacks`